# How to do smooth sprite movement on WP7 XNA

Tags: xna, sprites, windows-phone-7

What's the correct technique for getting smooth sprite translations with XNA?

I've been developing the WP7 version of an app for a startup, so when we heard Angry Birds got ported today we wanted to check it out and compare. Angry Birds on WP7 had the sub-pixel blur problem with the bird sprites, whereas iPhone, Android, and Chrome all had smooth movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like they are accidentally rounding their sprite positions to the nearest pixel. This can happen automatically if you use the SpriteBatch.Draw() call that takes a Rectangle as the position of the sprite, since XNA's `Rectangle` uses integers instead of floats to represent position.

If sprites are drawn with integer coords, then sub-pixel rendering will not occur, and sprites will appear to snap from one pixel position to the next, instead of blending smoothly between them.

Comment: That explains why, would the assumption for a fix then be to use the overload that accepts a Point()?

Comment: [You mean a `Vector2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx), and yes. And to make sure that the floating point coordinates in the `Vector2` struct are not being rounded to an integer value!

Comment: Snapping to the nearest pixel can however make for a clearer image, for example when using SpriteFonts, however this I only tested on Windows.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly whether the blur is occurring because of the sub-pixel rendering or because of the perceived blur from snapping to pixels. Which one actually results in the clearer image, at least in the context of little sprites on a cell phone screen flying around with Box2D physics?

Comment: Haha, yes. Can you tell I was working in a different .NET stack, where its Point instead of Vector2?

Comment: bearcdp: What perceived blur from snapping to pixels? Sub-pixel rendering will look better when sprites are moving.

Comment: 3nixios: Good point. If sprites are not moving, then you actually don't want sub-pixel rendering. Sub-pixel rendering means that color will be added to several pixels around the pixel location, to give the appearance of a pixel "between" hardware pixels, instead of coloring just a single hardware pixel. So a sprite will be slightly blurred if you place it between hardware pixel positions. That said, the question is about moving sprites -- which will almost certainly look better with sub-pixel positions unless they are moving very, very slowly.

Answer (score 2):

It could have to do with the framerate or it could have to do with the fact that xna does sub pixel rendering